# AngularJS: How can I select multiple checkboxes using shift and mouse click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, md-select

Is it possible to use shift and mouse click to select multiple elements on a table using AngularJS?

I have a table in which the first column is a checkbox and I would like to use SHIFT key and mouse click in order to select multiple rows continuously and can do things like delete, edit them etc.

Example by steps:

1. Click on 1st row's checkbox.
2. Hold down SHIFT key.
3. Click on 10th row's checkbox.

Result: the first 10 rows will be selected.

Does anyone know how this can be done using **AngularJS**?

Comment: It's not a duplicate since he wants to do it with Angular - and jQuery is *definitely* not needed for this. A custom directive will do fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar requirement. And while it's true that the *proper* way to update the checkboxes is by directly updating the model I wanted a more general solution.

So I built a pair of directives so I can reuse it on any checkbox list. Basically you wrap all the checkboxes with `<multi-checkbox-container>` and then add a `multi-checkbox` attribute to each checkbox. The code does the rest. Simple and easy.

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    $scope.checks = {};
    $scope.botigues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

  })
  .component('multiCheckboxContainer', {
    controller: function () {
      var ctrl = this;
      var checkboxes = [];
      var checkboxModels = [];
      var previousClickedCheckbox = null;
      
      ctrl.addCheckbox = addCheckbox;
      ctrl.onCheckboxClick = onCheckboxClick;
      
      function addCheckbox(checkbox, checkboxModelCtrl) {
        checkboxes.push(checkbox);
        checkboxModels.push(checkboxModelCtrl);
      }
      
      function onCheckboxClick(checkbox, shiftKey) {
        var start, end, i, checking;
        if (shiftKey && previousClickedCheckbox) {
          checking = checkbox.prop('checked')
          start = checkboxes.indexOf(previousClickedCheckbox);
          end = checkboxes.indexOf(checkbox);
          if (start > end) {
            start = start + end;
            end = start - end;
            start = start - end;
          }
          for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            checkboxes[i].prop('checked', checking);
            checkboxModels[i].$setViewValue(checking);
          }
        }
        previousClickedCheckbox = checkbox;
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('multiCheckbox', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: ['^^multiCheckboxContainer', 'ngModel'],
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
        var containerCtrl = controllers[0];
        var ngModelCtrl = controllers[1];
        containerCtrl.addCheckbox(element, ngModelCtrl);
        
        element.on('click', function (ev) {
          containerCtrl.onCheckboxClick(element, ev.shiftKey);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as vm">
  <multi-checkbox-container>
    <div ng-repeat="botiga in botigues">
      <input type="checkbox" multi-checkbox ng-model="checks[botiga]">
      <label>Botiga {{botiga}}</label>
    </div>
  </multi-checkbox-container>
  <p>checks = {{ checks }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete solution, but this should work for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/AvGKj/705/

just keep track of each lastChecked checkbox, and on shift+click, mark all the checkboxes as checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked = 'appObj.checked'  ng-click="checked($index, $event)">

$scope.checked = function($index, $event){

        if($scope.lastChecked && $event.shiftKey){
           for(i=$scope.lastChecked; i<$index;i++){
             $scope.myAppObjects[i].checked=true;
           }
        }
        $scope.myAppObjects[$index].checked=true;
        $scope.lastChecked = $index;
        }
```

this code would only work if you ckeck from 0 - positive integer , but not reverse, you wuld require to do some modification to make it work completely.

hope this helps

Comment: Your solution was very helpful, the only problem presented when you try to start by checking the first's row checkbox. I fixed that, and I posted below as correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Below presented the solution (Special thanks to Naeem Shaikh):
http://jsfiddle.net/dmakris/AvGKj/709/

HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <table class='table table-bordered'>
  <tr ng-repeat="obj in myObjects">
   <td>{{obj.id}}
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked = 'obj.checked' ng-click="checked($index, $event)">
   </td>
   <td>test {{obj.id}}</td>
 - </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Javascript (AngularJS) code:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.myObjects = [{id: 1, checked:false}, {id: 2, checked:false},      
                     {id: 3, checked:false}, {id: 4, checked:false},
                     {id: 5, checked:false}, {id: 6, checked:false}, 
                     {id: 7, checked:false}];

  $scope.checked = function($index, $event){
  if(typeof $scope.lastChecked !='undefined' && $event.shiftKey){
   for(i=$scope.lastChecked; i<=$index; i++){
    $scope.myObjects[i].checked=true;
   }
  }
  $scope.lastChecked = $index;
  $scope.myObjects[$index].checked=true;
 }
}
```